# Parsing Json string by using Gson gives me error

Tags: android, gson

I can't for the life of me figure out why I am getting

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

I have probably read through 15+ stackoverflow pages and tried a bunch of solutions for the entire day.

I have a simple websocket listener that returns a string everytime a message is sent from my websocket server.

```
@Override public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: Recieved: " + text);

}
```

it returns the String:

```
{ 
   "camera_id":"e9502c54-927c-4639-a94f-8d03149c9c62",
   "posted_by":"14b07da5-1820-40db-8508 cc81261458aa",
   "posted_by_user":"david23",
   "message":"hello world"
}
```

I am successfully getting each item using my model class

```
public class Message {

    private String camera_id;
    private String posted_by;
    private String posted_by_user;
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    ... rest of methods
}
```

And inside my onMessage listener...

```
try{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Message message = gson.fromJson(text, Message.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: " + message.getMessage());
}catch (Exception e){
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: Error: " + e);
}
```

I am successfully extracting the message key's string, but gson keeps throwing me this error and I CAN'T FIGUREOUT why.

```
Exception: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Some solutions have told me to confirm that the json sent from the server is a string. I have double, triple, countless times checked that it's a string.
Even made sure using.. String.valueOf(text)

Could someone help me pinpoint the cause of the error?

**Edit1:________________________________________________**

Using Roaim's method to check if my returned string contains {}, it says it doesn't, but my logs are telling me it does. How can this be?

[image]

```
onMessage: Recieved: {"camera_id":"e9502c54-927c-4639-a94f-8d03149c9c62","posted_by":"14b07da5-1820-40db-8508-cc81261458aa","posted_by_user":"david23","message":"hello world"}

onMessage: hello world

Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String evan.com.websocketchatapplication.Message.getMessage()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: post what Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: Recieved: " + text); prints.

Comment: It prints the string I listed above

Comment: including {} ??

Comment: Yeah includes  {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Exception: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:  Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path $

The above exception indicates that GSON was expecting the string to be begun with `{` but it got something else.

If you can ensure that the string begins with `{`, then the above exception will be gone. Let me show you how can you ensure that,

```
public Message jsonToMessage(String json) {
    if (!json.contains("{") || !json.contains("}")) return null;

    String text = json.substring(json.indexOf("{"));
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(text));
    reader.setLenient(true);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(reader, Message.class);
}
```

> **Answer to the Edit1:**

From observing the log, it looks like the `onMessage()` method is called twice with one valid JSON and one invalid text i.e. `Message Processed in Lambda!`. If I am not wrong, then simply ignoring the null `Message` object is fine. By the way, you can check the text for which my method returning null to figure out the issue,

```
public Message jsonToMessage(String json) {
    if (!json.contains("{") || !json.contains("}")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: jsonToMessage: " + json);
        return null;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: It is returning null meaning it doesn't contain {}. But my logs are telling me contains it. Check my edit above

Comment: FINALLY. You identified the issue. My websocket was returning two messages, the first one was successfully processed, however the second one was being sent by my callback function, and could not be processed, causing the error. Thanks a bunch for your help, I've spent all day trying to spot the mistake!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your api on postman it will show the actual response which u got from the server under "Preview" section.

Comment: no, postman only work with HTTP methods but you can use  chrome app of postman

Answer (score 0):

In your Message class replace -

```
    private String camera_id;
    private String posted_by;
    private String posted_by_user;
    private String message;
```

with -

```
    @SerializedName("camera_id")
    @Expose
    private String cameraId;
    @SerializedName("posted_by")
    @Expose
    private String postedBy;
    @SerializedName("posted_by_user")
    @Expose
    private String postedByUser;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

   /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public Message() {
    }
```

Comment: I'll test it as soon as I get home

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately it did not work. However my string returned says it does not include {} even though my logs say it does

Comment: try to parse it manually -
try{
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(text);
}catch(JSONException e){
//Log the exception and see what it says
}

@davids.